# Not able to upload data on server

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, image-uploading

I am using alamofire 3rd party library for uploading image, here my code to upload image over server but always same error like

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))   ▿ failure : AFError
>       ▿ responseSerializationFailed : ResponseSerializationFailureReason

Help me please

```
    self.uploadRequest = Alamofire.upload(fileData, to: url, method: .put, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (result) in

        completionHandler(result)

    }).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

        print(progress.fractionCompleted)

    })
```

Comment: How do you generate your `fileData` variable? Is it possible you are encoding your image incorrectly?

Comment: Yes i am correctly encoding data

Answer (score 0):

When using Alamofire's *responseJSON* The error :

```
"Invalid value around character 0."
```

is very common when the result of your webservice is not JSON formatted.

Check your webservice result by logging the body of the response or even by checking in a browser or in postman(chrome extension).

Almost a 100% sure you'll find something else than the expected JSON(html 404/500 error for example)